# Mapquest route matrix response

Tags: mapquest

Hi I am using mapquest api to show the distance from source to destination in app

Problem:

I am sending below request to mapquest to get the distance

```
{ "locations":[ "40.2336,-111.6475", "33.621227,-111.917229","30.688181,76.706238"], 
"options":{ "allToAll":true, "unit":"k", "doReverseGeocode":false,"manyToOne":true } }
```

Now in this case distance can be calculated from first lat long to second lat long as both are US based address but distance cannot be calculated between first and third location as third one is Indian location .

Now the response I am  getting is

```
{"route":{"routeError":{"message":"","errorCode":0}},"info":{"copyright":
{"text":"© 2015 MapQuest, Inc.","imageUrl":"http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
"imageAltText":"© 2015 MapQuest, Inc."},"statuscode":400,
"messages":["We are unable to route with the given locations."]}}
```

Which I suppose is wrong as distance between first two places should be returned .

Please suggest what can be done for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the matrix fails if any of the legs fails. Making this return any successful legs is on the team's backlog.

Comment: Mapquest still has not fixed this problem in Oct 2023.

Comment: Hi Ryan. Using the example provided originally, the distance and time is returned for the valid locations with a message that says, "Partial success. Time/Distance not found to all locations." If you're still seeing complete failure, please post a sample request and we can take another look. Otherwise, this was fixed quite a while ago but not announced here.

Comment: That's good news. For me yesterday, it was failing without that "partial" message, but it succeeded once I removed my most-recently-added-to-the-matrix destination, which used a plus code style address instead of a street address. https://maps.google.com/pluscodes/

Comment: Plus Codes are definitely not supported by the MapQuest APIs at this time. The team is looking into it but nothing set in stone yet.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that your locations are invalid. I ran it with the exact `POST` body you had, and got error 402. Looking at the [MapQuest Directions API Status Codes](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/directions-api/status-codes/), this is an invalid location. This makes sense, considering the coordinates include two in the US and one in India. This, AFAIK, is only a driving API, hence why overseas locations are invalid.

Another point unrelated to the main problem: your request is semantically invalid. You specify both `allToAll` and `manyToOne` as true, which is invalid. The API will ignore your `manyToOne` as a result, so make sure you are requesting exactly what you want.